# Error :uses or overrides a deprecated API Flutter in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

hi developes I  just start making  a new app and a  error show up "" uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. "" what that mean and how can i recompile with -Xlint .This error is ocuur in android studio when building a apk.

Comment: Hi there. This is just destrcriptive. You would have to include actual text from the stacktrace by copy pasting it here.

Comment: It's just a warning, moslty a deprecated api is being used by some plugin/package. This can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error,it is just a warning
if you are using other packages it has some deprecated api,
No need to worry about that

Comment: But why apk build failed

Comment: apk build is not failed for that please the console output so that we can solve the issue